# Heroku build Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`

Tags: angular, heroku

When deploying my angular app on heroku plafform am receiving this error log.

I have been following this link to configure angular-cli.json and some more stuff.

https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

```
    -----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       > angular-5-formularis@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_254071f3c66ba5811ab2e3b07c9696c2
       > ng build --prod

Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-5-formularis@1.`0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-5-formularis@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ekujC/_logs/2019-10-18T18_19_38_109Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: Could you check if you have the property app in your angular cli json file?

Answer (score 0):

I have already fix this, just moving angular-cli.json to the root of the project.